Profile Submission from an external site - "No secret provided" error
We have CiviCRM running on WordPress. I'm wanting users of an external site to be able to submit data through a profile embedded in an iframe on that external site.
I created a WordPress template that only displays the page content (and nothing else, no headers, footers, etc.). I created a page with that template that displays the desired CiviCRM profile and nothing else.
When I load that page in my browser, I can successfully submit the profile. And the profile form successfully loads in the iframe on the external site. However, when I submit the profile within the iframe, I get the following error:
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. No secret provided
I have the "Accept profile submissions from external sites" setting set to Yes in Misc settings.
Any ideas? I'm running CiviCRM 5.80.1 on WordPress 6.7.1.
